# Late model MacBook Air 13

Tags: macbook-pro

I’m very new to OS X.  Just bought my first Apple – Macbook 13.  I downloaded “ObsidianMenuBar” to change the menu bar to a black background.  It worked but now some of the letters are white and some remained black and thus invisible.  I’m told I need to install the “WhiteUIServer.menu” but I don’t have a clue how to do this.  Can someone kindly stir me in the right direction?  Sorry for showing up with hat in hand asking for help…

Answer (score 1):

From the Obsidian Menu Bar page:

```
To give the Clock, Battery and Fast user switching menu items readable
text, copy WhiteUIServer.menu by Alex Zielenski to somewhere on your
harddrive and open it. Also add it to System Preferences> Users & Groups>
Login Items to keep the text tray.
```

"Somewhere" on your hard disk could be, say, in your Documents folder. Basically any place that you know where it is and are unlikely to muck with it later, e.g., move it. When you've placed it where you want it to be, double click it.

Last, add it to your account's login items: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2602

That article is a bit old, but the basics are the same in later versions of OS X.